# Can I just directly copy software such as Firefox with all plugins to another computer through Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: installation, remote-desktop, plugins

I have to work on a remote computer and am able to copy files to it from my local desktop. A lot of my software such as Firefox and Spring Tool Suites have many custom plugins installed and it would be a pain to track them all down again. Can I just directly copy these software folders over, or do I have to install from scratch on the new remote machine?

The local machine is Windows 7, the remote machine is Windows 8.

Comment: Some software will work, others won't. Software which uses the registry to store information will not have that information on the other machine if you are only moving files. Firefox in particular is reasonably portable via their profile system though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You just need to move the profile data for Mozilla Firefox

1: Copy the profile data from following two folders in **Computer A**

*(example profile data folder 3n15dxtx.default)*

```
     %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
     %LOCALAPPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

2: Paste the profile data folders in above mentioned location of **computer B**

3: Append **.old** to the existing profile data folder in other **computer B**

4: Rename copied folders **(folder from computer A)** with the name of folders in **computer B**

```
i.e. if you copied ntbtzy20.default to a folder containing 3n15dxtx.default
rename 3n15dxtx.default to 3n15dxtx.default.old first & then rename 
ntbtzy20.default to 3n15dxtx.default
```

5: Launch Firefox and you should have all your information there

Comment: Thanks, are profiles specific to Firefox, or do many programs such as Spring Tools Suite/Eclipse have their own variation of it?

Comment: It is not specific to Firefox as Google Chrome does have profiles too and there are many other. But Eclipse does not have it and cannot say about Sprint Tools Suite as i haven't used it

Comment: Eclipse has "workspaces" which function similarly to (but not exactly like) profiles.